# Configuring a UIImagePickerController in a UITabBarController in a UIStoryboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard

I have a project using Storyboards. The initial ViewController is a UITabBarController which hosts two ViewControllers, the first of which is a UIImagePickerController.

Where should I configure the UIImagePickerController(set its sourceType etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

How about in the app delegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[self.window rootViewController];

    // Per OP, first view controller in the tab bar is the UIImagePickerController.
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    // Your configuration code here: 
    // imagePicker.sourceType = <your code here>

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The OP says the image picker controller is in a tab bar controller.

Comment: Verified solution as working. The tabBarController is usable.